# Are websites that make medical claims to cure herpes actually a scam?

Tags: herpes, cure

For example, [this website](https://www.hekmac.com/en/shop2/herpes-simplex-virus-hsv1-hsv2-supplements-copy/) makes the following medical claims:

> You will permanently get rid of HSV, and it will not come back as long as you are not infected again from another person who has the virus.

> You will get negative blood test result for HSV after finishing the course, which means you have completely eliminated herpes virus from your body.

The site claims that the treatment only costs $1,500!

Are these medical claims a scam?

If it is not a scam, why aren't more people aware? If so, how are the operators of the website allowed to get away with it?

Answer (score 7):

While I can't comment on the details of whether or not you have come upon a scam, I would expect any genuine new treatment to be accompanied by a full justification fit for the regulatory authorities, including  scientifically convincing reports of trials and more fundamental researches acknowledged by experts in the field.

What I can offer on this is that clearing out viruses of the herpes family is specially difficult -- relative to several other virus families, though perhaps this family of viruses may not be the most difficult of all.

Herpesviruses have evolved many features that enable them to escape or partly escape immune surveillance.  They can go latent -- for example the varicella zoster virus of chickenpox that can reactivate from latency many years later, to appear as shingles. Other herpesviruses as well, including HSV (herpes simplex virus) can remain in the body uncleared in latent form (see for example this on [herpesvirus latency](https://www.frontiersin.org/research-topics/7875/herpesvirus-latency), referring to the way that many herpesviruses 'establish lifelong persistent infection in the host').  Some herpesviruses even have devices to inhibit the display of their protein fragments at the cell surface, tending to evade the immune surveillance of cytotoxic T-cells, one of the important tools of the immune system for eliminating virus-infected cells (see ["Herpesviruses and immunity: the art of evasion"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20303681/), which discusses the frustrating ability of these viruses to "thwart[] the ability of cytotoxic T lymphocytes to recognize and eliminate virus-infected cells" and the "subversion of the natural killer cell response by herpesvirus proteins and microRNAs").

Treatments are among the points summarised in this WHO (World Health Organization) [factsheet](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/herpes-simplex-virus): the acyclovir antivirals ( acyclovir, famciclovir, valacyclovir) seem to be among the best available so far, see also these [treatment summaries from the relevant UK National Institute ('NICE')](https://bnfc.nice.org.uk/treatment-summaries/herpesvirus-infections/), but even these medications most often don't clear the virus especially from its latent form and they have to be given repeatedly.

So these viruses can be a very hard nut to crack, and for credibility of any new treatment or management of them I would personally expect to see something much more substantial than a herbal advertisement.

Comment: Good answer, thank you.

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to the site :)